# rJAGS version of write.model()?

Tags: r, winbugs, jags, r2winbugs

The R2WinBUGS package has a function called `write.model()`. The R package rjags has no such function of which I am aware. `write.model` creates a temporary text file that can be read as a model by WinBUGS.

I know I can enter `write.model` into the console to see the function, but this function seems to make calls to function that I've never seen before, and can't search for in `help()` (e.g., `replaceScientificNotationR` is apparently a function).

I saw [This Post](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/inlining-jags-models-in-r-scripts-for-rjags/) that describes some methods for doing this, but if possible, I'd prefer to not have to use the quotes (just to maintain my syntax highlighting), and a comment suggested that "copying the write.model function" should be doable.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: There's also the `R2jags` package, which lets you pass models as functions (e.g. @KevinWright's `jfun6`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you could just load `R2WinBUGS` to get access to the function.

However, in general, where there is a function that you can't see the code for, try `getAnywhere`.

E.g., `getAnywhere(replaceScientificNotationR)` produces:

```
A single object matching ‘replaceScientificNotationR’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:R2WinBUGS
with value

function (bmodel, digits = 5) 
{
    env <- new.env()
    assign("rSNRidCounter", 0, envir = env)
    replaceID <- function(bmodel, env, digits = 5) {
        for (i in seq_along(bmodel)) {
            if (length(bmodel[[i]]) == 1) {
                if (as.character(bmodel[[i]]) %in% c(":", "[", 
                  "[[")) 
                  return(bmodel)
                if ((typeof(bmodel[[i]]) %in% c("double", "integer")) && 
                  ((abs(bmodel[[i]]) < 0.001) || (abs(bmodel[[i]]) > 
                    10000))) {
                  counter <- get("rSNRidCounter", envir = env) + 
                    1
                  assign("rSNRidCounter", counter, envir = env)
                  id <- paste("rSNRid", counter, sep = "")
                  assign(id, formatC(bmodel[[i]], digits = digits, 
                    format = "E"), envir = env)
                  bmodel[[i]] <- id
                }
            }
            else {
                bmodel[[i]] <- replaceID(bmodel[[i]], env, digits = digits)
            }
        }
        bmodel
    }
    bmodel <- deparse(replaceID(bmodel, env, digits = digits), 
        control = NULL)
    for (i in ls(env)) {
        bmodel <- gsub(paste("\"", i, "\"", sep = ""), get(i, 
            envir = env), bmodel, fixed = TRUE)
    }
    bmodel
}
<environment: namespace:R2WinBUGS>
```

Thus, it is an internal function in the R2WinBUGS package.
Alternatively, you could download the [package source from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2WinBUGS/index.html) and explore.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to copy the write.model function unless you want to. The trick is to use write.model with textConnection. For example:

```
require(nlme)
require(rjags)
require(R2WinBUGS)

jdat <- list(nobs=nrow(Rail), travel=Rail$travel, Rail=Rail$Rail)
jinit <- list(mu=50, tau=1, tau.theta=1)

jfun6 <- function() {
  for(i in 1:nobs){
    travel[i] ~ dnorm(mu + theta[Rail[i]], tau)
  }
  for(j in 1:6) {
    theta[j] ~ dnorm(0, tau.theta)
  }
  # mu ~ dnorm() works fine since the mean is far from 0
  # mu ~ dgamma(1, 0.0001) could be used to ensure positive numbers.
  # mu ~ dnorm(50, 0.0001) I(0,) also ensures positive numbers.
  # We use truncation to show a difference between rjags and R2WinBUGS.
  # R2WinBUGS needs a dummy operator %_% that will be removed.
  mu ~ dnorm(50, 0.0001) %_% I(0,)
  tau ~ dgamma(1, .001)
  tau.theta ~ dgamma(1, .001)
  sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
  sigma.theta <- 1/sqrt(tau.theta)
}

# Save the jfun6 function into a text object called jmod6
tc1 <- textConnection("jmod6", "w")
write.model(jfun6, tc1)
close(tc1)

# Read the text object
tc2 <- textConnection(jmod6)
j6 <- jags.model(tc2, data=jdat, inits=jinit)
close(tc2)
c6 <- coda.samples(j6, c("mu","theta", "sigma", "sigma.theta"), n.iter=100000, thin=5)
summary(c6)
```